# SourceTree - using .gitignore

Tags: git, sourcetree

I use the SourceTree app to use Git. Within my project I installed files using composer. Now I have 26.000 files in my working copy, but I now want to start with my changes and with a working copy that shows 0 changes.

I tried it with a .gitignore file in my projects root folder. But still - for example I can see files within the media/folder. Why is this the case and do you have a hint how I can start with a working copy from 0.

[image: SourceTree]

[image: .gitignore]

Comment: "I now want to start with my changes and with a working copy that shows 0 changes" - I am not sure I understand what you want here. If you want your changes to be in, then commit them. The working copy afterwards will show 0 changes. If you do not want your changes to be in, use `git checkout` or `git reset` to go back to the version prior to your changes. **Do not ignore files that should be tracked.**

Answer (score 2):

According to the yellow icon on SourceTree, files on `media` directory are already tracked by git. That's why they are still listed by SourceTree despite the content of `.gitignore` file.

So you will have to untrack those files with `git rm --cached` command.
To do this with SourceTree, right click on the files you want to untrack, and choose *Stop tracking*.

Comment: Can I also untrack these in SourceTree?

Comment: Right click on the file > *Stop tracking*. It will stage some *remove* modifications that you will have to commit.

Comment: When I commit them, I do not want to push them to master. I only commit them?

Comment: If think you are mixing some git concepts. Your files are already tracked by git. So at one point, they have been committed, and maybe already pushed to your remote repo. Untracking them will only mean "I don't want to track those files anymore. To git, they are *removed*, but they will stay locally on my computer."

Comment: Ok, so if I select my 26000 files and select Untrack, commit and push them to the remote site the files are not tracked locally. But what happens if somebody else on the team does pull from the remote site? Is there any change to them as well?

Comment: If someone else pulls, the modification will be reflected to it's local repo and those files won't be tracked anymore. I suggest you to really rethink what are those files, and if they have to be under source control or not. It will help you to choose what to ignore.

Comment: They do not need to be under source control. Thats why I am wondering why they are, because I did not commited them. I just cloned the repo and did a compoer update... since then I see those 26000 files in SourceTree..

Comment: I have 16000+ files, any other solution to this?